# Calling RenderPartial from an Area

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, renderpartial

This is my folder structure

[image]

I wan to call a partialview from my view on my area

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could specify the full location of the view when rendering it:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/User/Views/SomeController/Foo.ascx"); %>
```

---

UPDATE:

And in order to call a partial from the `Shared` folder:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Foo.ascx"); %>
```

Comment: @Darin Hi, as you can see my *.ascx is not in an Area

Comment: It is what? I can't see? Are you trying to include a full ASPX page with renderpartial?

Comment: @Darin I think you misunderstood the arrows. I am calling the ascx which is under the default view>shared folder unto my Index.aspx page which is inside an Area.

Comment: @geocine, well then isn't `<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Foo.ascx"); %>` doing the job for you?

Comment: @Darin Hi darin i feel dumb it just worked after a few tries I messed up with the casing. Could you post a separate answer containing your last answer.

Answer (score 1):

geocine, please try this one.

<% Html.RenderPartial(Url.Content("~/Views/Shared/Foo.ascx")); %>

Does it solve your problem?